# How to solve error When create new project in eclipse?

Tags: android, android-sliding

When I create new android project in eclipse I facing below problem.

> Path: F:\ProjectWorkSpace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
>    [2016-03-03 10:37:14 - DownSlider]     Length: 1421457
>    [2016-03-03 10:37:14 - DownSlider]     SHA-1: fb6b7b885e8f62731e3f2fb9e64970e2d1d5ef5b
>    [2016-03-03 10:37:14 - DownSlider] Path: F:\ProjectWorkSpace\android-support-v7-appcompat\libs\android-support-v4.jar
>    [2016-03-03 10:37:14 - DownSlider]     Length: 1184450
>    [2016-03-03 10:37:14 - DownSlider]     SHA-1: e19387dc3b060af32f5401f84fbe246635256955
>    [2016-03-03 10:37:14 - DownSlider] Path: F:\ProjectWorkSpace\DownSlider\libs\android-support-v4.jar
>    [2016-03-03 10:37:14 - DownSlider]     Length: 1421457
>    [2016-03-03 10:37:14 - DownSlider]     SHA-1: fb6b7b885e8f62731e3f2fb9e64970e2d1d5ef5b
>    [2016-03-03 10:37:14 - DownSlider] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: why you are using 2 support v4 jars?

Comment: i use only one but when i use android-support-v7-appcompat library then i facing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete v4 jar from DownSlider libs folder ,copy jar from your android-support-v7-appcompat and paste it to DownSlider project libs folder this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Google has discontinued support for eclipse. Therefor your dependencies are outdated.

To develop android apps you now need [android studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) which is based on intellij

Answer (score 0):

It is because of different version of android-support-v4.jar (both have different size). Just replace the android-support-v4.jar from your library project with your project one.